# Не работает composer install

Tags: веб-программирование, composer

Есть файл composer.json нужно выкачать все файлы, открываю папку в консоли в которой находится файл json и пишу composer install, выдает ошибку "not found"

Comment: приведите полную ошибку, а не ваше "not found"

Comment: composer not found

Comment: Какая ОС? Как устанавливали?

Comment: MAC. После команды composer --version "Composer version 1.4.2 2017-05-17 08:17:52"